# Is using std::copy to work around strict aliasing safe?

Tags: c++, reinterpret-cast, strict-aliasing, type-punning

I have a function that looks like this:

```
template<typename T>
void some_function(T* buffer) {
    BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT(sizeof(T) <= sizeof(unsigned int));

    unsigned int temporary_buffer;
    int result = some_c_api(&temporary_buffer);
    if(result == error)
        throw some_exception();

    // originally *buffer = reinterpret_cast<T&>(temporary_buffer), but this breaks 
    // strict aliasing
    std::copy( reinterpret_cast<char*>(&temporary_buffer), 
               reinterpret_cast<char*>(&temporary_buffer) + sizeof(T),
               reinterpret_cast<char*>(buffer));
}
```

Is it safe to cast both unrelated buffers to `char*` here and copy the number of bytes the target buffer can hold? I am using a non-C++11 compiler (gcc 4.1.2).

I came upon this while refactoring some code. The original code did not have this warning because it was passing around buffers as `void*`. Am I correct in assuming that this was illegal?

Comment: Is `temporary_buffer` really an `unsigned int`? And are you really copying `sizeof(T)` bytes from that `unsigned int`s address? Are there any guarantees about `sizeof(T) <= sizeof(unsigned int)`?

Comment: Yes, it really is like that. There is static assertion at the beginning of the function that ensures `sizeof(T) <= sizeof(unsigned int)`.

Comment: Whoops, missed the assert completely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This piece of code looks like disaster waiting to happen. If it has to exist for some reason, it should be stuffed with static assertions and comments to make the intent clear.

Basically, it will work only if these conditions hold:

- `sizeof(T) <= sizeof(unsigned int)` (because you're copying from an `unsigned int` into a `T`). I see this is alreay asserted, fine.
- `T` is trivially copyable (as per the C++11 [`std::is_trivially_copyable`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_trivially_copyable) trait). If your compiler doesn't support the Boost equivalent of this trait, just document the requirement.

As long as these are met, it's fine. That's what trivially copyable actually means - it can be copied byte for byte. I'd just use `unsigned char` instead of `char` to stress the fact that it's bytes, not characters.

Comment: All these conditions hold (and are enforced in the actual code). This is what it looks like when writing wrappers for ugly C apis.